# For loop skipping iterations

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I have a for loop which will iterate through all choices and and set a value for them.
For some reason, when I run the code it does the first iteration, then skips to the last and does that one 3 times, or so according to the console.

code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
    console.log(i)
    var generated = word
    
    while (generated == word) {
        generated = wordsJson.characters[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordsJson.characters.length)]
    }

    choices[i].innerHTML = translate(generated)
}
```

What I get in console:

```
    0
(3) 3
```

This is my first time asking something on stackoverflow. If you need more information, please ask.

Comment: I notice you're not declaring `i` in the snippet above. Do you happen to have another loop somewhere else in your code, where you also use `i`? _(maybe in `translate`?)_ Always declare your variables with `let`, `const` or `var` so that they are scoped appropriately, and not global

Comment: And what is `word` and where does it come from?

Comment: If `word` is not defined in outer contexts, your code should show an `error`.

Comment: It was just like blex said. I've been coding all night and you tend to make some stupid mistakes after a while :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *appears* that the variable `i` is getting modified outside of the `for` loop.

Typically you would want to declare your iterator variable (in this case `i`) so that it's scoped to the loop, which would look like:

`for (let i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) { ... }`

Note, specifically, the addition of `let`. Since you haven't done that, it means that either `i` is already explicitly declared somewhere or, if not, that you've created a new global variable `i`.

Since you've got code you haven't shown that also seems to relate to `i` (`choices[i]`) and methods that we don't know the exact function of (`translate()`) it's hard to say for certain, but that would be the first place to look.

If not, posting some additional code so we can see the other functionality would be helpful.